# The entered dijit value doesn't display on the Json string

Tags: javascript, dojo

could you please help me to find the problem, here the json string doesn't display the dijit fields values.

**here HTML code**

```
    <script>
        require(["dojo/parser", "dojo/json",
                 "dijit/form/FilteringSelect",
                 "dijit/form/TextBox",
                 "dijit/form/Textarea",
                 "dijit/form/Button",
                 "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox",
                 "dijit/form/DateTextBox"]);
    </script>   
</head>
<body class="claro" bgcolor="pink" onload='disablet()'>
    <h1>PRODUCT MASTER</h1>
    <div class="grouping" id="divid">

        <label for="pcode">PRODUCT CODE:</label>
        <input type="text" name="pname" id="product code" value="" required="required"
        data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" data-dojo-props="regExp:'[^\d{1,10}$]+', invalidMessage:'Invalid enter only number between 1-10.'" />
        <br>

        <label for="pname">PRODUCT NAME:</label>
        <input type="text" name="pname" id="product name" value="" required="required"
        data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" data-dojo-props="regExp:'[a-zA-z]+', invalidMessage:'Invalid enter only Text.'" />
        <br>

        <label for="ptype">PRODUCT TYPE:</label>
        <select data-dojo-type="dijit/form/FilteringSelect" id="product type" name="ptype">
            <option value="rm">RAW MATERIALS</option>
            <option value="ip">INTERMEDIATE OPTION</option>
            <option value="fp">FINISHED PRODUCT</option>
        </select>
        <br>

        <label for="unit">UNIT MEASUREMENT:</label>
        <select data-dojo-type="dijit/form/FilteringSelect" id="unit measurement" name="unit">
            <option value="kg">KG</option>
            <option value="G">G</option>
            <option value="t">TONE</option>
            <option value="m">Meter</option>
        </select>
        <br>

        <label for="create">CREATED DATE:</label>
        <input type="text" name="CDATE" id="created date" value="1992-08-20" required="required"
               data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox"/>
        <br>
    </div>
    <button id="UPDATE" value="UPDATE" onclick="UpdateJSON()">UPDATE</button>
    <h1>JSON</h1>
    <span id="spnJSON"></span>
</body>
```

**javascript code**

```
function UpdateJSON() {

    var json = {PRODUCTCODE : 2, PRODUCTNAME : 'dd', PRODUCTTYPE : 'fg', UNITMEASUREMENT : 'g', CREATEDDATE : '2007-12-05'};

    var purchase = eval('(' + json + ')');
    purchase.PRODUCTCODE=dijit.byId("product code").value;
    purchase.PRODUCTNAME=dijit.byId("product name").value;
    purchase.PRODUCTTYPE=dijit.byId("product type").value;
    purchase.UNITMEASUREMENT=dijit.byId("unit measurement").value;
    purchase.CREATEDDATE=dijit.byId("created date").value;

    json = JSON.stringify(purchase);
    dojo.byId("spnJSON").innerHTML = json; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put spaces in your element id's. That's why dijit can't find them.

Maybe you could replace the spaces with underscores

```
<input type="text" name="pname" id="product_code" ...>
```

and

```
purchase.PRODUCTCODE = dijit.byId("product_code").value;
```

Comment: hi Skwal, i modified that changes, once again it shows same error. if i'm using document.getElementById instead of dijit.byId i got output. my question is using dojo controls.